# Rotating points around another arbitrary point

Tags: c, linear-algebra

Given the following test code inside a function:

```
int orientation = 0;        // increments up to 359, then loops to 0
int tempx, tempy;
float radians = orientation * (M_PI / 180);

tempx = point->x;
tempy = point->y;

tempx = (int) (tempx * cos(radians) - tempy * sin(radians));
tempy = (int) (tempx * sin(radians) + tempy * cos(radians));

tempx = tempx + origin->x;
tempy = tempy + origin->y;
```

With the following points (relative to origin): `(-100, 0)`, `(0, -100)`, `(0, 100)` I get this strange plot:

[image: curved paths]

The blue and green lines are overlapping paths. The intersection at the middle (with the barely-visible yellow point) is the origin. All points are in the correct position when `orientation` is `0` or `180` but in a non-circular path at all other angles. I've done plenty of linear algebra in my time, but this has me stumped. I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something in C itself, or if I'm just not seeing the problem.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect this code to do, but it may be a problem that you're updating tempx and then using that value when you recalculate tempy, when you really want to use the original value of tempx.

Comment: @celeritas: Yep, that was it exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing `tempx` after rotating it. Try the following instead:

```
   tempx = (int) (point->x* cos(radians) - point->y* sin(radians));
   tempy = (int) (point->x* sin(radians) + point->y* cos(radians));
```

and see if that fixes things or not.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I will accept your answer once the site allows me. Thanks for the assist!